# Customized AWS SNS Notification for failed lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have many lambda which might fail with some errors. I have created Cloudwatch alarm for namespace Lambda with error metric. Also, created SNS topic and subscription.

When there is any error in lambda, I do get email. But email is very verbose and has basic information like Lambda function name, Metric Name etc. below is example. I want to customize this email with more concrete information like what exactly error is.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subscribing the email address to the alarm SNS topic directly, you can subscribe a lambda to format the error message and send the email.

You can send the email directly from the lambda, or you can send it to another SNS topic and subscribe your email to that.

Basically:

existing Alarm => trigger `SNS1`

SNS1 => triggers lambdaA

lambdaA => send SNSB

SNSB => myemail@example.com

otherwise you can send the email via SES from the lambda.